# Missing page numbers while using the tocloft package

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, tocloft

I need to use the `tocloft` package because I edited my list of figures and tables that it displays "Figure/Table 1..." in bold text before the name using `\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\bfseries Figure/Table }`, `\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{6em}` and `\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0em}`. Later I noticed that because of the `tocloft` package, the page numbers on both pages for the lists are missing as well as the page number of the first page of the table of contents. When I comment `tocloft` out everything is numbered correctly but I can't use the commands mentioned above. Is there a way to display the page numbers correctly while using `tocloft` or is there a better way of achieving my desired outcome without the `tocloft` package?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example to make your question clearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `tocloft` package uses the `\pagestyle{plain}` for the first pages of the ToC, LoF and LoT. Within the package this is set by the macro `\tocloftpagestyle{plain}`, see page 6 of the user manual (`>texdoc tocloft`). You can change this to whatever you want but it seems as though you might have an errant `\tocloftpagestyle{empty}` in your code (which you haven't disclosed to us).

Or did you mean that the page numbers of chapters/sections etc. were not printed in the ToC?